# How to convert 2 binaries to a short in C

Tags: c, binary, short

signed:

```
short convetToSignedShort(uint8_t first, uint8_t second)
{
  signed short j;
  j = (signed char)first + (signed char)second;

  printf("signed short: %d\n", j);
  return j;
}
```

unsigned:

```
 short convetToUnsignedShort(uint8_t first, uint8_t second)
 {
   unsigned short j;
   j = (unsigned short)first + (unsigned short)second;

   printf("unsigned short: %d\n", j);
   return j;
 }
```

I know that I am not using the correct way.
I need for example `0x01 0x01` to be `257`, how can I do that?

Comment: You need to shift one of the values left by 8 bits.

Comment: the cast `(signed char)` are a bad idea because you can easily overflow a `signed char`. You need to decide which of the argument gives the higher bits to `*256`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this for unsigned:

```
uint16_t convertToUnsignedShort(uint8_t high, uint8_t low)
 {
   uint16_t j;
   j = ((uint16_t)high << 8) + (uint16_t)low;

   printf("unsigned short: %d\n", j);
   return j;
 }
```

For signed it makes less sense. What do you expect to happen with the sign bit of the low byte?